How to setup Webdriver manager to use chromedriver in a MacOS app compiled with PyInstaller?
In my python script I am currently using webdriver_manager (text) to install the chrome webdriver. This webdriver is used to create a Selenium driver to navigate websites and collect HTML data. This script works perfectly when running in python, but when I use PyInstaller, with the "--onefile" flag to convert it into a .app, the code does not work as expected. I am on an intel based Mac.
I think it might be an issue with MacOS and chromedriver, since on windows I have been able to compile the script to a .exe and have the webdriver_manager work as expected.
I tried multiple strategies. Here is a brief description of the solution I tried with an error code attached. The full function is located at the bottom.
In the first try block, in chrome_driver_setup() I tried the default installation method following the webdriver-manager documentation.
INFO:webdriverSetup:ChromeDriver not working. trying ChromeDriverManager().install() Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
In the second try block I attempt to use the service command from Selenium.
INFO:__main:running INFO:webdriverSetup:Error. Attempting other default chrome webdriver setup: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit:
In the third try block I attempt to use the chrome_autoinstaller library text following the documentation guides.
INFO:webdriverSetup:Error. Attempting autoinstaller: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
In the fourth try block I used an opener
INFO:root:Downloading chromedriver (127.0.6533.57)... INFO:webdriverSetup:Error. Attempting opener thing: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
In the fifth try block, I noticed the webdriver-manager, when ran as a .app, would not create the driver as an executable file and it would append THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES to the chrome driver making it impossible to run. Here is the error attached
NFO:WDM:====== WebDriver manager ====== INFO:WDM:Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome INFO:WDM:Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome INFO:WDM:Driver [/Users/bennet/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/127.0.6533.57/chromedriver-mac-x64/THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver] found in cache INFO:webdriverSetup:ChromeDriverManager, /Users/bennet/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/127.0.6533.57/chromedriver-mac-x64/chromedriver INFO:webdriverSetup:Tried everything and it's not working. Now attempting to remove driver and reinstall. Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
All of these cases do not work when the script is converted to a .app on Mac but does when it is in script format. If anyone could help with this issue, I would greatly appreciate it!
Full function attached here
def get_driver():
    if sys.platform in ["Linux", "darwin"]:
        try:
            return chrome_driver_setup()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info(f"Tried everything and it's not working. Now attempting to remove driver and reinstall. \n {e}")
            driver_path = shutil.which('chromedriver')
            # Remove the folder and everything inside it if the path exists
            if driver_path:
                driver_folder = os.path.dirname(driver_path)
                shutil.rmtree(driver_folder)
            return chrome_driver_setup()
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        return bing_driver_setup()

def chrome_driver_setup():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Bypass OS security model
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Overcome limited resource problems

    def make_executable(path):
        # Change the file permissions to make it executable
        st = os.stat(path)
        os.chmod(path, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)

    def is_executable(file_path):
        # Check if the file is executable
        return os.path.isfile(file_path) and os.access(file_path, os.X_OK)   
        
    def create_ssl_context():
        context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
        return context

    def create_opener():
        # Create a custom opener with our SSL context
        context = create_ssl_context()
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=context))
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    

    # I know this is disgusting. Please blame ChromeDriver and Pyinstaller with MacOS because they don't work well together
    try:      
        print("Attempting default chrome webdriver setup")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        try: 
            logger.info(f"Error. Attempting other default chrome webdriver setup: \n {e}")
            service = ChromeService()
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
        except Exception as e:
            try: 
                logger.info(f"Error. Attempting autoinstaller: \n {e}")
                chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
                driver = webdriver.Chrome()
                return driver
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    logger.info(f"Error. Attempting opener thing: \n {e}")
                    create_opener()
                    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
                    return driver
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.info(f"ChromeDriver not working. trying ChromeDriverManager().install() \n {e}")
                    executable_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
                    # need to do this because it installs incorrectly sometimes
                    if executable_path.endswith("THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver"):
                        executable_path = executable_path.replace("THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver", "chromedriver")
                    logger.info(f"ChromeDriverManager, {executable_path}")
                    if not is_executable(executable_path):
                        logger.warning(f"The file at {executable_path} is not executable. Attempting to fix permissions.")
                        make_executable(executable_path)
                    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
                    return driver


Check my answer for this question, may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78789819/issue-with-selenium-and-webdriver/78790315

i had similar issue to the one you mentioned that happend to you in the  fifth try block, im using linux not MacOS, but maybe this could help, an issue was placed two days ago in the driver-manager github.
https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/665
A pull request that solve the issue with the driver path was aproved, so maybe just updated to the lastest version of the lib.
If for some reason you dont want to update to the lastest version you can also just go and adjust the driver path manually, im the erro log you have you can see a directory name .wdm, so in there you should find a drivers directory and a drivers.json file. Edit the json file and change to part of the path that says THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver to chromedriver. Then go to .wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/127.0.6533.57/chromedriver-mac-x64 and make sure that the chromedriver file has execution rights.
i hope this helps.
