THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver - Exec format error - undetected_chromedriver
undetected_chromedriver with webdriver_manager was working well few days ago for scraping websites but out of nowhere it started throwing the error:
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 
'/Users/pd/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/127.0.6533.72/chromedriver-mac-x64/THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver'

I am guessing it is related to recent update of webdriver_manager.
This is the code:
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def get_driver():
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-sim-usage")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
    driver = uc.Chrome(driver_executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options, version_main=116)
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver

It would be really great if someone can help me on this, Thanks.

A similar thread. I was able to find a solution through the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78789819/issue-with-selenium-and-webdriver/78796998

it worked for me by upgrading webdriver manager, pip install --upgrade webdriver_manager and then removing that file that is causing error rm /home/username/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/129.0.6668.58/chromedriver-linux64/THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver

The command ChromeDriverManager().install():

creates a new folder without the executable and
it retrieves the wrong file.


First, you need to remove the .wdm folder and then reinstall webdriver-manager:
Windows Location:
r"C:\Users\{user}\.wdm"
Linux Location:
/home/{user}/.wdm
Mac Location:
/Users/{user}/.wdm
rm -rf /home/user/.wdm
pip uninstall webdriver-manager
pip install webdriver-manager

Now, after executing ChromeDriverManager().install(), you should only see a single folder with the executable:

It check if there is really a chromedriver executable inside this folder.
Second, it makes a correction to the file name:
if 'THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver' in chromedriver_path:
    chromedriver_path = chromedriver_path.replace('THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver', 'chromedriver')


This one worked for me.
But, i removed only the 127.0.6533.88 folder and not all the /.wdm folder

Many thanks for the very good instructions.

This answer works well, for Windows the .wdm path would be inside C:\Users\{username}\.wdm

on mac its something like '/Users//.wdm/'

Thanks for this. I had to manually add the check if 'THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver' in executable_path:     executable_path = executable_path.replace('THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver', 'chromedriver'). I also had to make the chromedriver executable using the line os.chmod(executable_path, 0o755). Hope this helps.


Chrome driver 127 has an additional file: THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver in the package run chrome driver. with webdriver-manager < version 4.0.2 will encounter an error in this case. Need to update webdriver-manager to version 4.0.2

It is related to the function __get_binary in the driver_cache.py file. webdriver-manager version 4.0.2 added the condition if 'THIRD_PARTY' in f: continue


Please update webdriver-manager to version 4.0.2 to solve the above problem.


It is related to the function __get_binary in the driver_cache.py file. webdriver-manager version 4.0.2 added the condition
if 'THIRD_PARTY' in f:
continue

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The issue was fixed in the latest 4.0.2 release. See this commit on `webdriver_ma for details.

I have a quicker and easier solution.
The problem is related to chromedriver 127.0.6533.88 which, after the update, directs execution to the THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver file.
Solution:
In C:\Users{user}.wdm edit the drivers.json file, replacing
"win64_chromedriver_127.0.6533.88_for_127.0.6533": {
"timestamp": "03/08/2024",
"binary_path": "C:\Users\{user}\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win6 4\127.0.6533.88\chromedriver-win32/THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver"
For
"win64_chromedriver_127.0.6533.88_for_127.0.6533": {
"timestamp": "03/08/2024",
"binary_path": "C:\Users\{user}\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win64\127.0.6533.88\chromedriver-win32/chromedriver.exe"
